# Tag synonym request: [user-accounts] -> [users]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Both tags cover the same area. [users] already has a tag wiki entry so I suggest keeping it as the master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed and done. But thanks to the minimum character limit, I have to write an essay before I can post this reposnse.

Good day to you sir.

Comment: I SAID GOOD DAY!

Comment: Good day, Oli, and thx. Are you getting impatient? :-))